# how can I change an state when clicking outside of a component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with a list of properties(picture 1), when I click in one, I change de `detailsVisible` from the state from false to true and I show the component child(picture 2) I would like than when I click anywhere but in the details component the details component dissapear by switching the `detailsVisible` from true to false, I have try adding onblur function to each elemen of the list and adding a function to the main div but nothing works[image]

Comment: Please avoid pasting code screenshots, instead add a producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which represents the scenario.

Comment: sorry I did not mean it, I am working with 2 screens and did not realize the screenshot also had the secondary one, I did not want to show the code

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by adding default JS on click event to the body with addEventListener (in componentDidMount), removeEventListener (in componentWillUnmount) and checking if that event was triggered inside the rendered component.

You can add isDescendant helper:

```
function isDescendant(parent, child) {
  let node = child.parentNode;
  while (node != null) {
    if (node == parent) {
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const componentEl = document.getElementById('your-component-id');
  if ( isDescendant(componentEl, e.target) ) {
    //Change state
  }
});
```

RemoveEventListener is important here because that event is added externally and you can trigger an update to the state of the unmounted component.

Comment: where am I supoussed to use ```document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const componentEl = document.getElementById('your-component-id');
  if ( isDescendant(componentEl, e.target) ) {
    //Change state
  }
});```I have tried inside and outside the return

Comment: In componentDidMount().